# How do I correctly toggle between temperature degree units?

Tags: jquery, ajax, toggle

I'm able to display the fahrenheit temperature and toggle a button to display the celsius units correctly only one time. When I click again, it shows the wrong value in celsius and then stops displaying values altogether.

All of my functionality is nested within a getJSON request from open weather's API.

Here's my HTML:
```

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="description-wrapper">
            <div class="date-wrapper" id="date">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="location-wrapper" id="location">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="temperature-wrapper" id="temperature">
                <h3 class="weather-description"></h3>
            </div>
            <button class="toggleBtn" id="toggleDegrees">click to change between celsius and fahrenheit</button>
            <div class="author-wrapper">
                <p>Penned by jginbound</p>
                <p>Info provided by Open Weather API</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
Here's my JS code... I'm asking more about the code snippet that are under the comments: "toggle degree units here"

```

```
$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' +      latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&APPID=xxxxxx', function(data){
                console.log(data);

//get weather condition text
                var weatherCondition = data.weather[0].description;
                weatherDescription.html(weatherCondition);
                // weatherDescription.html(data.weather[0])

                //return kelvin temperature
                var kelvinTemp = data.main.temp;
                //display temperature in fahrenheit
                var degreeParagraph = '<p class="degreeUnit">';
                degreeParagraph += kelvinToFahrenheit(kelvinTemp);
                degreeParagraph += '<span>';
                degreeParagraph += degreeSymbol;
                degreeParagraph += '<a href="#" id="toggleDegreeUnit">';
                degreeParagraph += 'Fahrenheit';
                degreeParagraph += '</a>';
                degreeParagraph += '</span>';
                degreeParagraph += '</p>';
                weatherWrapper.append(degreeParagraph);

                //toggle Degree Units here

                $('#toggleDegrees').click(function(){
                    console.log($('#toggleDegreeUnit').text());
                    if($('#toggleDegreeUnit').text()==='Fahrenheit'){
                        var displayFahrTemp = kelvinToFahrenheit(kelvinTemp);
                        displayFahrTemp = fahrToCel(displayFahrTemp);
                        console.log(displayFahrTemp);
                        $('.degreeUnit').html('<p>' + displayFahrTemp + '<span>' + degreeSymbol + '<a href="#" id="toggleDegreeUnit">' + ' Celsius' + '</a>' + '</span>' + '</p>');
                    }else{
                        var displayCelTemp = kelvinToFahrenheit(kelvinTemp);
                        displayCelTemp = celToFahr(displayCelTemp);
                        $('.degreeUnit').html('<p>' + displayCelTemp + '<span>' + degreeSymbol + '<a href="#" id="toggleDegreeUnit">' + ' Celsius' + '</a>' + '</span>' + '</p>');
                    }
                });
            });
```

```

appreciate your feedback! also any feedback on code structure/organization/efficiency will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the code.

1) Call the ajax function $.getJSON(...) inside $('#toggleDegrees').click();

2) Why can't you have static tag of "" and dynamically update the text on $('#toggleDegrees').click() event.

3) Use debugger; in the script code of $('#toggleDegrees').click() script and verify the output from Ajax function and try it.

Comment: This is my main issue, it seems. I can't continue to toggle between both degree units. It works once, but then stops after two clicks. http://codepen.io/johnnyginbound/pen/QEBbNw?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see here is that the HTML string you construct is the same in both the `if` and the `else` statement.

`$('.degreeUnit').html('<p>' + displayCelTemp + '<span>' + degreeSymbol + '<a href="#" id="toggleDegreeUnit">' + ' Celsius' + '</a>' + '</span>' + '</p>');`

Since you have *Celsius* as the text in `#toggleDegreeUnit` for both strings, when you query that in your `if` statement, it always comes back as Celsius and thus will go down the `else` path every time after the first one (since you default to Fahrenheit). If you change the `degreeUnit` in the `else` statement to be *Fahrenheit*, the code will trigger back and forth properly.

Also, make sure to remove the space before your unit, otherwise the `if` statement won't match!

EDIT: I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8jqqLdk/10) for you to show a different way to organize your code more efficiently by abstracting the string building process into a single function.

Comment: thanks, Lance! I'll give this a try. and thank you for the fiddle :)